# Extracting unique values from row in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement, duplicates

I need to summarize unique values from a row into a column that's in the same row. My goal is in the second row of the attached image where `T:Z` contains the data and `AA:AC` contains the summary (I typed the values in for the demo). The first row is what is currently occurring where I tried using a nested if function for values greater than zero, but I also tried using an index match function to no avail. The issue is I either receive duplicates in `AA:AC` or not all values are included.

[image: Summary goal]

Currently using Excel 2016

Comment: Where does the "Poor colon prep" come from?  That's not in your source data.

Comment: Care to let us know the decision making of the Summary cells from those columns?

Comment: Hello, Patrick, I need the data in the summary columns because I am forcing a new data extract into an old data set. The old data set only had one reason. My hopes are to simply add the new columns of reasons to the old data set. Tim, the "Poor colon prep" is likely in column S.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you are going to have a sheet of rows of data. You want to look in the columns T:Z and then generate a list of unique values (non-zero) in the columns AA:AC. I assume that you know you will never have more than 3 unique values, but I can't be sure that this wasn't just an omission.

Either way, the below code should work:

```
Sub Find_Uniques()
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, Z As Integer
    Dim Temp_Strings() As String
    For X = 1 to 10000 'This assumes you don't have more than 10,000 rows of data
        ReDim Temp_Strings(1 to 5) As String
        For Y = 20 to 26
            If Range(Cells(X,Y).Address).Value <> "" And Range(Cells(X,Y).Address).Value <> 0 Then
                For Z = 1 to 5
                    If Temp_Strings(Z) = "" Then
                        Temp_Strings(Z) = Range(Cells(X,Y).Address).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    If Temp_Strings(Z) = Range(Cells(X,Y).Address).Value Then Exit For
                Next Z
            End If
        Next Y
        For Z = 1 to 5
            If Temp_Strings(Z) <> "" Then Range(Cells(X,Z+26).Address)).Value = Temp_String(Z)
        Next Z
    Next X
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Instead of extracting the data from the row, I wrote a macro that changed the zeros to blanks, deleted the blank cells, and shifted them to the left. After that it was easy to cut the range and paste it into the old data set to be analyzed.

```
Sub clean_data()
Sheets("Reason data").Range("H:Z").Replace 0, ""

Call delete_blanks
End Sub
Sub delete_blanks()

Sheets("Reason data").Range("H:Z").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete (xlToLeft)

Call move_data

End Sub
Sub move_data()
'Copies reason data and pastes it into data worksheet

Sheets("Reason data").Range("A3:K3", Sheets("Reason data").Range("A3:F3").End(xlDown)).Cut _
Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End Sub
```